# Set multiple routes for same path in zuul

Tags: netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

When I run application I need it to register in multiple Eureka servers. So I am placing a Zuul in front of Eureka and route to both urls at the same time. Is this possible(for me this did not work), if not can anyone suggest a workaround for this.
I have tried separating urls with comma and it was not success either.

Zuul yml:

[image]

Comment: You can add code blocks in the question itself. I believe there is a reputation limit on adding images, but there is no such limitation on adding code.

Comment: Why do u want to register in 2 eureka-servers ?
What do u want to achieve?

Comment: If one eureka instance went down, I need a backup. Since I am working on local servers, I cannot scaling them up.

Answer (score 0):

> When I run application I need it to register in multiple Eureka servers.

That is possible with providing comma separated list of paths to multiple Eureka servers in `eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone`. You do not need to use Zuul for this.

Example (for a yml file):

```
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
        defaultZone:http://eureka-server1.com/eureka,http://eureka-server1.com/eureka
```

Please note that there shouldn't be any whitespace after comma in list of Eureka servers.

You can read more about using multiple Eureka servers [here](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Understanding-Eureka-Peer-to-Peer-Communication).

Comment: For same zone, this does not work, it wont register in 2 eureka servers at the same time. When server1 goes down, then it will register in server2, and once server1 comes back up, it will re-register in server1. 
Its a primary,secondary kind of model

Comment: And, if ur saying that 2 servers are peers of each other, then i dont think u need 2 specify those 2 servers for the same zone, as they will replicate information among themselves.

Comment: @IndraneelBende You do not register to 2 Eureka servers. You specify two defaulZone urls. Client keeps a list of healthy Eureka servers. Peer servers will have information replicated. Client sends pings to one server and if that server goes down client starts sending pings to next healthy Eureka server.

Comment: Registration is done to only one Eureka servers and since both Eureka servers are peers, that registration info gets replicated.

Comment: You are basically repeating what i said above :D

Comment: (i dont think u need 2 specify those 2 servers): But without specifying two servers, how will client know where is the second server located if the first server goes down (say VM crashes).

Comment: My first comment, was for 2 servers who are not peers of each other. 2nd Comment was for when 2 servers are peers of each other, in that scenario, i guess(I could be wrong), specifying one url would be good enough, as peers replicate information among each other.